# Selenium for Java: Getting started resources/tutorials

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anybody mention the resource/tutorials for learning selenium webdriver for java ?. I googled it but didn't find any for beginner level :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this page:  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

It has a simple example of a google search, and its how I learned.